# Define a column as struct in DBT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, dbt

I'm using `dbt seed` to create and populate a table on Amanzon Athena from a CSV.

I'd like to specify that one column of the seed has to be created as `struct<myfield:string>` but cannot find this option in the list of data types (https://docs.getdbt.com/sql-reference/data-types).

The CSV is exported as CSV from another Athena table and if I look at the file the struct is exported with this format:

```
"{myfield=foo.bar}"
```

I tried to specify the column as `JSON` but the import fails because that field is not in JSON format.
I also tried to use `string` as type, in that case the upload worked fine but the data is the table is stored as string (obviosly) and not as struct.